# Will I get an email if I purchase a digital Xbox game

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, xbox-network

Will I get an email if I purchase a digital Xbox game even though it's from a code?

Comment: What a strange question. Why are you asking?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer not strange if you want to keep transaction records, more so if you live in a country where certain goods can be claimed as a tax deduction on your tax and you're able to find a way to make games deductible

Comment: i am not sure about games but if your buy DLC on the XBox you have a recent emailed to the email address of the user who brought it. since these is the same as what Playstation does so assuming Microsoft would do the same as them you would also get an email for any game you get, free or otherwise (i never gotten a free game for my XBox, only brought DLC but when i get free games via code or though Playstation+ i get a receipt)

Comment: If you are talking about Xbox One or 360, you should get an email sent to whatever Microsoft account you have linked to your gamertag.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the Xbox One or Xbox 360, you should get an email sent to whatever Microsoft account you have linked to your gamertag that confirms purchase of the item.  The emails look something like this with a subject of "Your Microsoft order of [Item Ordered]":

[image]